# Factor into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (Eisenstein Integers).

Tags: ring-theory

$\mathbb{Z}[\omega] = \{a + b\omega : a, b\text{ are integers}\}$

$\omega = e^{2πi/3} = -\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt3}2i$

My task is to factor the numbers $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.  I don't know if I'm overthinking this, but I do not even know where to start.

I'm used to doing this in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$, but I have no idea how to approach $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.

EDIT: I am not supposed to use the norm in this exercise.  My biggest struggle right now is just figuring out how to factor these numbers.  Using guess and check I was able to find:

$$3 = (2 + \omega)(1 - \omega)$$

$$7 = (3 + \omega)(2 - \omega)$$

I'm plugging and chugging into Wolfram Alpha right now. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: It will be enough to know about reducibility/irreducibility of the ordinary primes $2,3,5,7,11$. As elsewhere, the norm is a useful tool. Compute the norm of $x+y\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your input, André!  I have computed the norm to be (2a - b)^2 + 3b^2.  How can I use this?

Comment: The computation is not quite right. There will be a $2$ in the denominator. And I believe that there is a sign problem with the $3b^2$. The norm of a product is the product of the norms. So if the norm of $\xi$ is plus or minus a prime, then you know $\xi$ is irreducible. And if the norm of $\xi$ is not prime, you know the candidate norms of factors, and you may be able to show there is no element with that norm, or use the norm as a guide to factorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The norm, $N(a+b\omega) = (a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2) = a^2 - ab + b^2 = \frac{(2a-b)^2 + 3b^2}{4}$, will save a lot of time here.

For example, we can quickly find the factorization of $3$, because $N(3) = 9$, so when checking for non-trivial factors of $3$, we need only consider elements of norm $3$, which we can enumerate by solving $(2a-b)^2 + 3b^2 = 3 \cdot 4 = 12$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?  I've never done norms before and I am so lost.

Comment: @JamesNorton The norm satisfies $N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$, so it behaves well with respect to factorization.  If you want more details, let me know what is unclear.

Comment: I believe you should have $\frac{(2a-b)^2+3\color{red}{b}^2}{4}$ for the alternative norm.

Comment: @Mark You are correct.